Compile Error when opening an Excel spreadsheet from Access
I have various routines within an Access database system that open Excel, open a workbook, make changes before saving it, closing it and quitting.  Basically, I use this code:
Dim objExcel As Excel.Application
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

objExcel.Workbooks.Open "Filename.xlsx"

DO STUFF TO THE SPREADSHEET USING CODE

'Save spreadsheet and close down Excel
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Save
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close
objExcel.Quit
Set objExcel = Nothing

Just lately, I have been getting a message when a button click runs this code saying Compile Error - Object Library feature not supported.  This results in none of the code being run and the code being displayed with the objExcel.Quit line highlighted in yellow.  I have found that commenting out the Dim objExcel line makes this problem go away!  Typing 'objExcel.' on a new line brings up a list of commands to enter after the '.', but 'Quit' is not one of them.
Users open this database through a simple Login form.  Could I run the Dim statement and the Set objExcel statement upon opening the database and remove all instances of them from the rest of the database system?  Similarly with Word Documents.
Microsoft Excel/Word 16.0 Object libraries are correctly installed.
Thank you
I suspect that I might have to trace any duplicate Dim declarations that might possibly be affecting this, but with some being in Functions and some within other forms being open at the same time, there could be a conflict anywhere amongst this scenario.  I'm wondering if one declaration at the opening of the database will save me a lot of time sorting this out.

Dim objExcel As Excel.Application shows you are using early binding, so change the Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application") to Set objExcel = new excel. Application and recompile using option explicit. Also check the references and make sure Microsoft excel object library  is ticked.

In the VBA editor, click on objExcel and press Shift+F2 (Goto Definition). With that, you can check where the variable is defined - if you have multiple definitions, it should jump to the one that is actually used. What you could also do is to use the Locals or the Watch window to check what type objExcel is.

I couldn't replicate the problem.  after adding the Excel object library reference and providing a full pathname in place of just filename.xslx the code worked

Thank you for your comments and sorry for the delay acknowledging them.  I shall re-visit this over the weekend.
